# Delete Duplicate Opportunity Record, Keep Original Record

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

My goal is to write an apex trigger that will delete duplicate Opportunity Records based on the Opportunity Name but retain the first record that is created. I believe a before trigger would be the best option.

For example, if the name of the first Opportunity is "Opportunity Alpha" and another user creates an Opportunity called "Opportunity Alpha", I would like the second record to be deleted automatically. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered [native Salesforce Duplicate Management](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management)? It will make your life a **lot** easier.

Answer (score 0):

As David mentioned, Salesforce already offers standard functionality for managing duplicates. Creating an Apex trigger would not be necessary in a situation like this. Below is a link to documentation on duplicate management in Salesforce.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm&type=5